# Adding graphics to 404.php page

Tags: php, images

I am trying to customize the 404.php page by adding a graphic. I can figure out how to change the text and links, but the HTML I just don't know well enough to add a picture or graphic. I am using Church Theme from StudioPress.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

How are you changing the text and links? If you're editing a 404.php file, then you simply need to add html to output whatever images you want, i.e.:

`<img src="https://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" />`

Will output this:

[image]

For more on HTML, check out w3schools.com's excellent material: http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: For accessibility it's a good idea to add an alt tag as well. Before the closing tag, add alt="Google Logo" Substitute appropriate text.